# How to create an Outlook macro that updates a table's attributes to shrink a table to the contained text without wrapping?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, macros

***Updated:*** Updated Macro w/ fix.

#### Version: Outlook 2013

#### I want to be able to...

1. Alter the font-size of the text in the table. **(Done)**
2. Remove (uncheck) the "Preferred Width" attributes from the table, collumn, and cell active attributes.
3. Remove (uncheck) the "Specified Height" attribute from the table's rows.

If I use `aTbl.Columns.PreferredWidth = Unchecked` to compress the columns, it does a word wrap and doesn't uncheck the box.
I want it to NOT word wrap.

If i use autoFit, it looks the same as `aTbl.Columns.PreferredWidth = Unchecked`.

If i set the columns individually, it looks the same as `aTbl.Columns.PreferredWidth = Unchecked`.

#### Had to import the MS Word Object Library:

[image: MS Word Object Library Import]

#### What I have so far:

```
Public Sub FormatSelectedText()
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objInsp As Outlook.Inspector

    ' Add reference to Word library in VBA Editor, Tools, References
    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim objSel As Word.Selection
    'On Error Resume Next

    'Reference the current Outlook item
    Set objItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
        If objItem.Class = olMail Then
            Set objInsp = objItem.GetInspector
            If objInsp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
                Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
                Set objWord = objDoc.Application
                Set objSel = objWord.Selection

                objSel.Font.Size = 8
                Dim aTbl As Word.Table
                For i = 1 To objSel.Tables.Count()
                    Set aTbl = objSel.Tables.Item(i)
                    aTbl.Borders.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                    aTbl.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                    aTbl.Rows.Height = Unchecked
                    aTbl.Rows.AllowBreakAcrossPages = False
                    aTbl.Columns.PreferredWidth = Unchecked
                    aTbl.Columns.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthAuto
                    aTbl.PreferredWidth = Unchecked
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objWord = Nothing
    Set objSel = Nothing
    Set objInsp = Nothing
End Sub
```

#### What it looks like before Script:

[image: Before]

#### Expected Result:

[image: Expected Result]

#### After Running w/out `aTbl.Columns.PreferredWidth = Unchecked` (close but doesn't compress the columns):

[image: With PreferredWidth]

#### After Running w/ `aTbl.Columns.PreferredWidth = Unchecked` (Just.. No):

[image: Without PreferredWidth]

#### Example of the settings that need to be changed to alter the table correctly:

[image: Table Properties - Table]
[image: Table Properties - Row]
[image: Table Properties - Column]
[image: Table Properties - Cell]

Comment: That sounds nice. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I think i found how to update the font (untested), but can't find a way to update the table attributes.   
Found this site: http://www.slipstick.com/developer/word-macro-apply-formatting-outlook-email/

Comment: I've now gotten the Table Width and Row Height correct, but the cell width isn't working right.

Comment: What if you try using `.autofit`?

Comment: When I tried that it looked the same (messed up) as when i used `aTbl.Columns.PreferredWidth = Unchecked`

Comment: You're setting all your table attributes in your `for i = 2 to count` loop - so it's doing it x number of times. Try doing the formatting after the loop.

Comment: Not exactly. I'm setting the values for each selected table. If there is only one table selected, it will only do it once. `objSel.Tables.Count()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this has worked:

```
                aTbl.Columns.PreferredWidth = Unchecked
                aTbl.Columns.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthAuto
```

Comment: If I use those and move the `aTbl.PreferredWidth = Unchecked` to the end of the for loop, it works.